# Uploading images: Orientation

Tags: node.js, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, exif

I'm using Amazon-S3 to let users upload images. When the images are uploaded via mobile the orientation is correct on mobile. However all images uploaded via mobile device have incorrect orientation on desktops.

This is due to the images EXIF data I believe.

How do I rotate images according to EXIF on desktop?

Is this possible?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sure thing can you help me with my question then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong Image orientation when uploading - Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546375/wrong-image-orientation-when-uploading-amazon-s3)