# nodejs - how to prevent the exif image auto rotate

Tags: node.js, image-compression, imagemin

I am using `imagemin` to minimize the image size.

After that, I find that the minimized image changed from portrait to landscape, which is unexpected for me.

Is there any way to prevent it from rotating?

```
...

async function minimizeImage(data){

        var bufferFromImage = Buffer.from(data.image, 'base64');

        if ((bufferFromImage.length / 1e+6) > 5) {
            throw new errors.NotAcceptable("too large");
        }
        const miniBuffer = await minimizeImage(bufferFromImage);
}


const resize = async (input) => {

    return sharp(input)
        .resize(250)
        .toBuffer();
};

const minimizeImage = async (bufferFromImage) => {
    if ((bufferFromImage.length / 1e+6) > 0.1) {
        return await imagemin.buffer(bufferFromImage, {
            plugins: [resize]
        });
    } else {
        return bufferFromImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it by using `jpeg-autorotate` library.

There is a post related to this problem.
[Wrong Image orientation when uploading - Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546375/wrong-image-orientation-when-uploading-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there, your image maybe rotated in Sharp resize step. You can prevent rotate in Sharp by calling `rotate()` before `resize()`.

```
const resize = async (input) => {
    return sharp(input)
        .rotate()
        .resize(250)
        .toBuffer();
};
```